# hp printer gui not working

Tags: printing, hp

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 17.10 and a HP Deskjet 2540 printer/scanner. I sent a job to it that wouldn't print, so I tried to cancel it by going to `Settings > Devices > Printers`

[image: Screenshot 1]

I click on the `1 Job` button and bring up the list of active jobs. But from this page, the `Clear All` and x for the individual job don't work. They register being clicked on but the job doesn't disappear. Completely restarting my laptop doesn't get rid of the job either.

[image: Screenshot 2]

I did find this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne.
I entered `sudo hp-check -r` into the terminal and made sure everything required was installed. It's a bit long to paste everything, but here's the end of the output message to that command:

```
-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
None

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-notify2' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible

Total Errors: 3
Total Warnings: 1

Done.
```

Comment: `Settings > Devices > Printers` is part of HPLIP. Did you try to open `hp-toolbox` from terminal and find your printer here?

Comment: the already shows up in the hp-toolbox list with "unknown status". the job shows up with status "printing"